# Random walk on matrix until singularity

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, random-matrices, random-walks

Consider a random walk on matrices, where one starts with the matrix $M=I_n$ and at each step randomly chooses an entry of $M$ to increase by $1$.

I’m interested in two things about this walk:

1. What’s the expected number of steps until $M$ is singular?
2. What is the probability that $M$ never becomes singular?

Both problems are nontrivial even for $n=2$.

I would also greatly appreciate a reference for this.

Comment: You might have this already, but in the case $n = 2$, the probability that $M$ never becomes singular is 0. We define $A_n = M_{11} - M_{12}$ and $B_n = M_{22} - M_{21}$. Then $(A, B)$ is a random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, which is guaranteed to visit the origin, where $\det(M) = 0$.

Comment: For $n = 3$, I think there might be a non-zero possibility. Maybe lower bound the distance of each column from the origin and use some probabilistic argument.

Comment: Making some tries with $n=2,3,4,8$, the time to reach a singular matrix seems even slightly smaller with $n=3,4,8$. This rather suggest that that the probability that $M$ remains non-singular is zero regardless of $n$.

Comment: @YCor: Is it true that the _second_ (or third) time when the matrix is degenerate also comes soon? It could happen that there are many restrictions on the initial steps, but fewer restrictions afterwards…

Comment: What is the probability that the first two rows never become equal?

Comment: @RichardStanley That is the probability that the $n$-dimensional  lattice random walk never visits $(1,-1,0,\dots,0)$.

Comment: If the entries of an $n$ by $n$ matrix are bounded by $T$, the probability that it is singular is about $C \log T T^{-n}$. See [this article by Katznelson](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-93-06906-2). After $k$ steps the entries of the matrix are of size about $\sqrt{k}$, so you expect that it will be singular with probability $C'\log k k^{-n/2}$. For $n\ge 3$, by union bound, we expect that there will be a non-zero probability that $M$ will never be non-singular. This can probably be formalized and analyzed further using the method of the work above, which is related to the other comments.